# Drupal Views: Exposing Individual Fields on Output for Styling

Tags: css, templates, drupal-7, drupal-views, jcarousel

I've created a view which outputs a particular content type into a jCarousel.

One of my fields is a 'background colour' and I want to use this value for the actual background colour of the `li` element in my jCarousel. The next is an image and I want this image to be wrapped in a div that I can lay out correctly within the same `li` of the carousel.

So, this carousel will have a customisable image and background colour for each member of the content type.

The problem is, in jCarousel, the fields are just dumped into an array haphazardly, so I cannot output different fields in different ways. Ideally, what I'd like to happen is: in the `jcarousel-view.tpl.php` I'd like to output `$rows[0]['background-color']` into my custom html `div` tags and then `$rows[0]['image']` output into my own custom classed `div` tags also - obviously iterated within a loop to apply the individual settings to each element.
However, the current set up is that $rows[0] dumps both fields into their default styles and I can't access individual fields.

Now, is this something I can control in Views? Or do I need to do some custom hacking to get this to work?

Comment: have you tried working with the rewrite the output option in view? just click on any field in view edit page, you should see it.

Comment: @FunkyDude unfortunately I can't customise the fields, because jCarousel as a display format doesn't allow it.

Comment: I lie, changed it from Content to Fields and now I can customise. I'll get back to you after a play around.

Comment: @FunkyDude - make this an answer and I'll accept. You genius!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried working with the rewrite the output option in view? just click on any field in view edit page, you should see it.